# Exchange Service Issue .net Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I tried to execute the following code

```
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username@someone.com", "somepassword");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("username@someone.com");
```

The above code works in .net 4.7 but does not work on .net core 2.2

Error message is: 
[image]

I have to change the ExchangeVersion to Exchange2007_SP1 to make it works in .net core 2.2. However I would prefer to use Exchagne 2016 as some of my code is not working using exchange 2007.

I also have tried to use the following libraries:

1. Exchange.WebServices.Managed.Api
2. Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices

Does anyone have any solutions? thanks.

Comment: As a starting point i'd suggest you read https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues/96

Comment: hmm so it seems that at the moment it's not well supported from the link that you gave?

Comment: Yes but it's all open source now so you can support and modify it as needed